# React executing delegate passed to child via props

Tags: reactjs, delegates, components

i have a react component that is inserted into a page when a button is clicked. This component has a button that should execute `onUpdateClient` when clicked. it is not executing and i have no idea why... I'm completely at a loss... Moreover, I'm passing a delegate though `props` to this component and am wanting to execute the delegate from the above stated method... I'm hoping once i get the event handler to work, this will also work... Can someone call out any errors that they see that may be keeping this event handler from firing?

```js
class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      updateDisabled : false
    };
    this.onUpdateClient = this.onUpdateClient.bind(this);
  }

    onUpdateClient(){
    // tried to execute this way... but this method isn't even getting called... i dont understand :*(
    //const {updateClientCallback} = this.props;
    alert("in " + this.props.client.name);
    this.setState({updateDisabled: true});
    //updateClientCallback();
  }
  
  render() {
const {classes, client, updateClientCallback} = this.props;

return (
    <div>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={16}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="rose" icon>
              <CardIcon color="rose">
                <PermIdentity/>
              </CardIcon>
              <h4 className={classes.cardIconTitle}>
                Edit Profile - <small>{client.name} : {client.id}</small>
              </h4>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              //{...}
              <Button disabled={this.state.updateDisabled} onclick={this.onUpdateClient.bind(this)} color={updateClientCallback == null? "error" : "warning"}
                      className={classes.updateProfileButton}>
                Update Profile
              </Button>
              <Clearfix/>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
);
  }
```

this is the component that instanciates the above component

```js
class Clients extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: dataTable.dataRows.map((prop, key) => {
                return {
                    id: key,
                    name: prop[0],
                    position: prop[1],
                    office: prop[2],
                    age: prop[3],
                    actions: (
                        // we've added some custom button actions
                        <div className="actions-right">
                            <Button
                                justIcon
                                round
                                simple
                                color="primary"
                                className="edit"
                            >
                                <Person/>
                            </Button>{" "}
                            {/* use this button to add a edit kind of action */}
                            <Button
                                justIcon
                                round
                                simple
                                onClick={this.editClient.bind(this,key)}
                                color="success"
                                className="edit"
                            >
                                <Dvr/>
                            </Button>{" "}
                        </div>
                    )
                };
            }),
            alert: null,
            show: false,
            client: null,
        };
        this.editClient = this.editClient.bind(this);
        this.viewClient = this.viewClient.bind(this);
    }

    removeClient() {
        alert(this.state.client.name);
        this.setState({client : null})
    }

    editClient(key) {
        let client = this.state.data.find(o => o.id === key);
        this.setState({
            client: (
                <UserProfile {... this.props} updateClientCallback={this.removeClient.bind(this)} client={client}/>
            )
        });
    }

    viewClient() {

    }

    inputConfirmAlert(e) {
        this.setState({client: e});
    }

    hideAlert() {
        this.setState({
            alert: null
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>

                {this.state.client}
                <GridContainer>
                    <GridItem xs={12}>
                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader color="primary" icon>
                                <CardIcon color="primary">
                                    <People/>
                                </CardIcon>
                                <h4 className={classes.cardIconTitle}></h4>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <CardBody>
                                <ReactTable
                                    data={this.state.data}
                                    filterable
                                    columns={[
                                        {
                                            Header: "Name",
                                            accessor: "name"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: "Position",
                                            accessor: "position"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: "Office",
                                            accessor: "office"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: "Age",
                                            accessor: "age"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: "Actions",
                                            accessor: "actions",
                                            sortable: false,
                                            filterable: false
                                        }
                                    ]}
                                    defaultPageSize={10}
                                    showPaginationTop
                                    showPaginationBottom={false}
                                    className="-striped -highlight"
                                />
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are binding `onUpdateClient` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the culprit lies here:

```
onclick={this.onUpdateClient.bind(this)}
```

There are some problems with this bit:

- It's supposed to be `onClick` instead of `onclick`.
- You are binding `onUpdateClient` twice, inside the constructor and inside the event handler.

So I suggest 2 possible fixes:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onUpdateClient = this.onUpdateClient.bind(this);
  }

  onUpdateClient(){
    // Your code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onUpdateClient}>
          Update Profile
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or

```
class UserProfile extends Component { 
  onUpdateClient(){
    // Your code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onUpdateClient.bind(this)}>
          Update Profile
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The first fix is more preferable as the event handler is reused across renders, therefore give your app a small performance boost (depends on how expensive a component is really). The second method creates a new function every time the component re-renders, which will clearly slow down your app in the long run

Forgot to mention, if a JS transpiler is installed, this syntax is also possible:

```
class UserProfile extends Component { 
  onUpdateClient = () => {
    // Your code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onUpdateClient}>
          Update Profile
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Looks nice and neat doesn't it? :)

For further reference, please visit [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: Please don't do this: `<Button onClick={this.onUpdateClient.bind(this)}>`. This will generate a new function reference every time this component is rendered. Either bind it on the constructor or use the transpiler. -- You might think "but it's just one little function"... But when you get the habit and you end up in a page with hundred of components it adds up (and eats your memory and slows down your application).

Comment: @SergioMoura thanks for the suggestion, but I already included this information in my answer

Comment: sorry about that. I only read it later... It irks me every time I see it. I work with a codebase with about 1200 components... Things can get slow fast! Also, you nailed the `onclick` vs `onClick`.

Comment: Haha, true. When it comes to best practices, I feel the same @SergioMoura

Comment: Thank you guys for giving me such good advice. I'm only a few days into react, so all of this is super helpful.

Comment: @TraeMoore if it helps, please give it an upvote and tick. Cheers